# Wifi lenovo e450 not connecting

Tags: wireless

I have found several people having similar issue, but not the solution

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo E450

I was able to connect on a wifi once, for a while, but after some time, whenever it tries to connect, message "Disconnected: you are now offline" appears. I am able to connect to some wifis (i can connect to a mobile hotspot i created) but for example not the wifi i have at home (which everyone is using and its working just fine)

I am kind of helpless as of what might be the problem, what should i try to solve this

Comment: Please [add to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/677161/edit) the results of the wireless info script from [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/178596) - the information should help solve your problem.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7JN5sWUd this should be it (while not connected to any wifi and trying to connect to my home wifi)

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 power_save=0 swcrypto=1 bt_coex_active=0"
```

and reboot.

Comment: this didnt do the trick :/

Comment: @ViRPo Please try the new one.

Comment: @Pilot6: You're losing it!  You're showing up in the low quality review queue!  (Voted "Looks OK")  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Since Pilot6's answer didn't work `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Delete the line that was added
`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 power_save=0 swcrypto=1 bt_coex_active=0`

And add
`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8`
Save, exit gedit, and reboot

I had an Intel card that wouldn't connect on a wireless network that was 11n only until I used this option to enable aggressive TX